# MongoDb capped sub-collection

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to create a capped sub-collection. I'm trying to do something like:

```
user = {
  name: String,
  latest_messages: [String]
}
```

Where the `latest_messages` are capped to 10.

If not, what do you suggest as an alternative?

**Update 1:**

It appears as though keeping the array capped manually is the only solution. Here's a way to do this:

```
joe = {name: 'Joe', latest_messages: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']}
db.users.save(joe)

db.users.update({name: 'Joe'}, {$push: {'latest_messages': 'hello'}})
db.users.update({name: 'Joe'}, {$pop: {'latest_messages': -1}})

db.users.update({name: 'Joe'}, {$push: {'latest_messages': 'world'}})
db.users.update({name: 'Joe'}, {$pop: {'latest_messages': -1}})
```

Any suggestions on making this more efficient?

**Update 2:**

There's an [open Jira ticket, "SERVER-1050"](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) that requests to add the ability to do the two (push & pop) as one atomic operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only specify the overall number of documents of a capped collection.
There is no way limit the size of an array unless through some checks in your app.

Comment: do you see any way of making it more efficient than what I have above?

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2.4 there is a feature to allow doing this called "capped arrays". This allows you to `$push` documents to an array in conjunction with `$each`, `$slice` and `$sort` operators to add one or more documents to the array while maintaining given size, sorting by specified field of subdocuments.

See exact syntax and examples [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#fixed-size-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a separate capped collection for each user? So the name of the collection is the name of each user. I don't know if MongoDB becomes slow if you have many collections? How many different users do you have? Something like 100, 1000, 10000...?

Comment: Say 100,000. This feels like a non-standard usage of collections. Are there any performance implications?

Comment: It seems there is a maximum: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections

Answer (score 0):

There is a request on their JIRA board that is nearly 2 years old to do exactly this. It has been scheduled to be added to the next version of mongodb since 1.6 so I wouldn't hold your breath.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-991